# Inserting a QSection to QRootElement at runtime in QuickDialog iOS

Tags: ios, quickdialog

I am building a form with [QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/quickdialog) library in iOS. Here it is possible to insert any QElement at an index into any QSection dynamically with this method

```
- (void)insertElement:(QElement *)element atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

But I found no way to insert a QSection into my QRootElement at runtime. Is there any way I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to you do this:

You can either use the `- (void)addSection:(QSection *)section;` method on the QRootElement to add the section to the bottom of the root, or you can insert the item directly in the `sections` mutable array property of the rootElement.

We should probably add a `insertSection:atIndex:` method for consistency, but it doesn't exist today.

Comment: Great to see you in my question here :) . I checked the above methods available before posting my question here. In both ways, new section will be added at the bottom of the root. But my case is a bit different, I have another 2 sections under a QRadioSection , I have to add new Section when user selects a particular option on that QRadioSection and I also have to remove it and add some other when other options are being selected. I guess, I have to remove the bottom 2 sections , add my required section and then add the deleted 2 sections again if I want to do it like this.

Comment: As I get you here, I would like to ask another question. Can I add a custom UITableViewCell in my QuickDialog form ? If It can be done, can you please give me some hint, link or sample code so that I can understand and do it ? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: you should be able to do `[root.sections insertObject:item atIndex:5]` to insert a new section between existing ones.